# Group elements in 2 lists in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm trying to group elements from two lists.

Basically what I want is: given a genre input by console, show artists who have songs in that genre and the average popularity is equal or greater than `N`

Example of console input:

```
./exe -g Pop 80
```

I'm new in C and don't know exactly how to do this. I have 2 .txt files that I'm reading and saving their attributes in struct arrays. That part of the code works fine.

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it. Or if my approach is correct.

Clearly, the last part where I try to group them is not working since each array has a length of 130.000. And I'm doing 3 for loops, so, 130.000^3 iterations.

I need a more efficient way to do it.

genres.txt looks like this:

```
...
R&B;6jvvpPJQJy5rMOEkLlADl6;Trey Songz
R&B;6p8JTP4A9NZHtxRVhkEo6s;T-Pain
R&B;3SwhPTNNU5hpF33bbCsji6;BJ The Chicago Kid
R&B;5yvhdo8FXbBsIllxv2Rr94;SZA
R&B;5Yq38evNk28qlTVHHtwBhT;James Blake
R&B;5yamjs92dcayRVlNuY116G;H.E.R.
R&B;4FjcZsKyGhhZnuYq0nzXpZ;T-Pain
R&B;22jnEneSABg4vRCR1vow7F;Daniel Caesar
R&B;57qiTKh8bVX0VtfUNTQqhw;The Weeknd
...
```

songs.txt looks like this:

```
...
2y9CiiXaeZUdX3ZjsnkCVb;1;Minor
316vZ2FFcGlhI7XDld9fay;6;Minor
321MDop1sPmNMO0UQE4EcJ;0;Minor
35W7MQyH36gNt3EoR0qZdV;0;Major
38QPdO8qO4xuavpeHF1oyr;3;Major
3AnPOKKZV1NRhED24p9YeX;7;Major
3Cr09kBxG7FE9fvbSPlcIN;0;Major
3Ez6AS04xRmFq3K7wr7ayj;0;Major
3GgYVk6uLkNNuE2O7zHhvZ;0;Major
...
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct genresFile{
    char* genre;
    char* idSong;
    char* artist;
} genresFile;

typedef struct songsFile{
    char* idSong;
    int popularity;
    char* mode;
} songsFile;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* songs = fopen("songs.txt", "r");
    FILE* genres = fopen("genres.txt", "r");
    
    genresFile* genresList = NULL;
    songsFile* songsList = NULL;

    char *buf = malloc(256);
    char *tmp;
    int i = 0, j =0;
    while (fgets(buf, 255, genres)){      
        genresList = realloc(genresList, (i+1)*sizeof(genresFile));
        if ((strlen(buf)>0) && (buf[strlen (buf) - 1] == '\n'))
            buf[strlen (buf) - 1] = '\0';       
        genresFile object;
        tmp = strtok(buf, ";");
        object.genre = strdup(tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        object.idSong = strdup(tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        object.artist = strdup(tmp);

        genresList[i] = object;
        i++;
    }
    i =0;
    while (fgets(buf, 255, songs)){      
        songsList = realloc(songsList, (i+1)*sizeof(songsFile));
        if ((strlen(buf)>0) && (buf[strlen (buf) - 1] == '\n'))
            buf[strlen (buf) - 1] = '\0';       
        songsFile object;
        tmp = strtok(buf, ";");
        object.idSong = strdup(tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        object.popularity = atoi(tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        object.mode = strdup(tmp);

        songsList[i] = object;
        i++;
    }

    
    for(;j<i;j++){
        double avgPopularity = 0;
            for(int n = 0; n < i; n++){
                if(strcmp(genresList[n].artist, genresList[j].artist) && strcmp(genresList[n].genre, argv[2])){
                    for(int z = 0; z <i; z++){
                        if(genresList[n].idSong == songsList[z].idSong) avgPopularity += songsList[z].popularity;
                    }
                }
            }
        avgPopularity = avgPopularity/j;
        printf("%s: %d\n", genresList[j].artist, avgPopularity);
    }
   
    free(genresList);
    free(songsList);
    fclose(songs);
    fclose(genres);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tWbN.png)

Thanks for the help and let me know if I missed any details. :D

**EDIT**

I did a qsort for genresList as you suggested and then did a binary search. But my binary search is not finding any results. Printing `Item could not be found` with the debug code.

This is currently my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct genresFile{
    char* genre;
    char* idSong;
    char* artist;
} genresFile;

typedef struct songsFile{
    char* idSong;
    int popularity;
    char* mode;
    genresFile* genre;
} songsFile;

int compareGenre(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const genresFile *u1 = v1;
    const genresFile *u2 = v2;
    return strcmp(u1->idSong, u2->idSong);
}

int compareSong(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const songsFile *u1 = v1;
    const songsFile *u2 = v2;
    return strcmp(u1->idSong, u2->idSong);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* songs = fopen("songs.txt", "r");
    FILE* genres = fopen("genres.txt", "r");
    
    genresFile* genresList = NULL;
    songsFile* songsList = NULL;

    char *buf = malloc(256);
    char *tmp;
    int i = 0, j =0;
    while (fgets(buf, 255, genres)){      
        genresList = realloc(genresList, (i+1)*sizeof(genresFile));
        if ((strlen(buf)>0) && (buf[strlen (buf) - 1] == '\n'))
            buf[strlen (buf) - 1] = '\0';       
        genresFile object;
        tmp = strtok(buf, ";");
        object.genre = strdup(tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        object.idSong = strdup(tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        object.artist = strdup(tmp);

        genresList[i] = object;
        i++;
    }
    i =0;
    while (fgets(buf, 255, songs)){      
        songsList = realloc(songsList, (i+1)*sizeof(songsFile));
        if ((strlen(buf)>0) && (buf[strlen (buf) - 1] == '\n'))
            buf[strlen (buf) - 1] = '\0';       
        songsFile object;
        tmp = strtok(buf, ";");
        object.idSong = strdup(tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        object.popularity = atoi(tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        object.mode = strdup(tmp);

        songsList[i] = object;
        i++;
    }
    free(buf);


    qsort(genresList, i, sizeof(genresFile), compareGenre);
  
    for(;j<i;j++){
        genresFile* result;
        result = bsearch(&songsList[j].idSong, genresList, i, sizeof(genresFile), compareSong);
        songsList[j].genre = result;
         if( result != NULL ) {
            printf("Found item\n");
        } else {
            printf("Item could not be found\n");
        }
        free(result);
    }
     
    
    free(genresList);
    free(songsList);
    fclose(songs);
    fclose(genres);
    return 0;
}
```

I debugged the qsort and it is sorting correctly but the binary search is not working. This is my first time using search.

I would be doing this in Python but I'm a student and this is for a school project. And it is a requirement to do it in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a matter of programming language but of algorithm. First, you need a quick way to look up the genres for each song. To do that, you can first sort the genres by that long key, then do a binary search using the key.

Your structs should be as follows:

```
typedef struct genresFile{
    char* genre;
    char* idSong;
    char* artist;
} genresFile;

typedef struct songsFile{
    char* idSong;
    int popularity;
    char* mode;
    genresFile* genre; // extra field
} songsFile;
```

So once you read both songs and genres, you sort the genres by key. You then loop through all the songs an binary search the genre in the genres array and fill up the genre field to point to the proper element in the genresFile array.

Assuming you have n songs and m genres, sorting costs `m log m`, filling up the genres field costs `n log m`.

Next, sort the songs by artist at a cost of `n log n`. Loop through all songs to determine the list of k artists that have at least one song of that genre.

Store these k artists keys in an array and sort that array. Next, loop through the songs array to filter out the songs who's artist does not belong to the k artists determined in previous step. You can use binary search to search through the k artists. Cost `n log k`.

Finally, you have to group by artist and average and filter by average popularity.

Doing all of this in Python would be a breeze. In C, there is qsort and bsearch to help.

Storing the data in SQLite then querying the database would cut down the code to close to nothing.

Code in Python that should do the job:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Read genres dataset and rename columns assuming there is no header
    genres_df = pd.read_csv('genres.txt', delimiter=';', header=None)
    genres_df.rename(columns={0: 'genre', 1: 'songid', 2:'artist'}, inplace=True)
    
    # Set songid as index
    genres_df.set_index('songid', inplace=True)
    
    
    # Read songs dataset and rename columns assuming there is no header
    songs_df = pd.read_csv('songs.txt', delimiter=';', header=None)
    songs_df.rename(columns={0: 'songid', 1: 'popularity', 2: 'mode'}, inplace=True)
    
    # Set songid as index
    songs_df.set_index('songid', inplace=True)
    
    # Selected parameters
    genre = 'R&B'
    popularity = 4
    
    # Join each genre record with the corresponding song record
    song_genre_df = genres_df.join(songs_df)
    
    # Filter by genre
    song_genre_df = song_genre_df[song_genre_df.genre == genre]
    
    # Get the average for each artist
    average_df = song_genre_df.groupby('artist').mean()
    
    # Filter by popularity
    average_df = average_df[average_df.popularity > popularity]

    # Output
    average_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you know what good comparison function would work to use with qsort? Since there are letters and numbers.

Comment: You should write the comparison function. Your comparison function will have two pointers to the elements you are sorting. You then compare them the way you want and return 0, -1 or 1 for equal, less or greater. Your comparison function is a callback. It will be called by qsort and bsearch. Look up some examples online. Write a simple program to play with qsort and bsearch then integrate them in your program. Do things progressively and make sure things work before moving to the next stage. Use separate functions to do each action.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if you are happy with the answer. I wish you the best Rodrigo. Are you a student?

Comment: @Tarik im new to programming,so I'm wondering,how would it be easier to do this in python instead of c?don't you need to write the same logic that you mentioned in both languages?

Comment: Ok, will work on it and share some code when back home. C is good for system programming and other tasks but no good for quickly handling this kind of task. That does not mean Python is better than C. Python happens to be more appropriate for this task.

Comment: See sample code. Note the following: I only pick the average out the popularity of the songs that match the selected genre. That means that if an author writes songs in more than one genre, only the selected genre songs' popularity will be averaged for that author. I assumed there are no header lines in genres.txt and songs.txt.

Comment: Note that you can use command line arguments as in C and also grab the data from a URL or database instead of text files.

Comment: I posted an edit if you could help me, please.

Comment: You remind me of a project I had to do in C back in the 90's. Give me some to time and I will help the best I can. Meanwhile, try to follow the broad outline I gave you, one step at a time.

Comment: Could you provide the input files.

Comment: Write a function to dump the data after each step. To make sure sorting is ok.

Comment: bsearch only works on a sorted array. Did you sort the array you are searching in?

Comment: I managed to do the bsearch and filter the artists by genre. I stored the k artist in an array. I have to just make them unique. Because I'm storing all artists even if they repeat themself. What do you mean by dumping the data?

Comment: I mean storing the data in  a CSV file to see if the step is successful by looking at the data at each step

Comment: By making unique, you mean that you want to aggregate the data.

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant

Comment: Did you make it or do you need further help. You are doing well by the way! Keep it up!